# How to plot and save pie chart and bar graph using same plt from matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, data-visualization, pie-chart

I need to plot and save pie chart and bar graph using same plt from matplotlib in python.
While using plt for both pie chart and bar graph and displaying them in html, second plot is coming as an overlapped figure of first one.
Can you please suggest the method for the same?

Answer (score 0):

*Matplotlib* isn't stateless, so basically you're always using the **same** plot.

First things first: spare yourself some hustle. `Matplotlib` is a pain to work with it directly. If you want to get nice plot fast, use [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/), which is just aggregator over `Matplotlib`. As `Matplotlib` isn't stateless, you need to clean things up, to avoid artifacts. I just use wrapper, which I decorate every plotting function with:

```py
def __disposable_plot(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        plt.figure(clear=True)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        plt.close('all')

    return wrapper
```

If you need kickass plot, use [ploty](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py).

Comment: Thanks. I used plt.close() after saving each plot. And it worked.